# Standard sorting functions in SML?

Tags: sml

Are there standard sorting functions in SML? The documentation on the Internet is so scarce I couldn't find any.

Comment: what are you trying to sort?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by scarse, but the [SML Basis Library](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/) homepage is a good place to look up functionality

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no sorting functionality defined in the SML Basis Library, but most implementations extend the basis library and add extra functionality.

As such MosML has both an [ArraySort](http://www.itu.dk/%7Esestoft/mosmllib/Arraysort.html) and a [Listsort](http://www.itu.dk/%7Esestoft/mosmllib/Listsort.html) module, and SML/NJ has a [LIST_SORT](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/listsort.html) signature with a ListMergeSort implementation. It also features some other sorting features on arrays as MosML. See the [toc](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/toc.html) of the SML/NJ Library Manual, for a full list.

Answer (score 5):

As Jesper Reenberg points out, Standard ML compilers have each their own (non-standard, ironically) sorting libraries. Since the documentation for these lacks examples, here is how to sort a list of strings in ascending order using the various modules:

1. In SML/NJ and MLton, using the [`ListMergeSort.sort`](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/listsort.html) function:

   ```
   - fun sortStrings ss = ListMergeSort.sort (fn (s : string, t) => s > t) ss;
   [autoloading]
   [library $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm is stable]
   [autoloading done]
   val sortStrings = fn : string list -> string list
   - sortStrings ["World","Hello"];
   val it = ["Hello","World"] : string list
   ```

   The quirk with this library function is that it takes a "greater than" boolean predicate. Since Standard ML's `>` operator is overloaded, but defaults to *int*, I have to somehow explicitly annotate that I'm comparing *strings*.
2. In Moscow ML, using the [`Listsort.sort`](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/mosmllib/Listsort.sig) function:

   ```
   - load "Listsort";
   > val it = () : unit
   - fun sortStrings ss = Listsort.sort String.compare ss;
   > val sortStrings = fn : string list -> string list
   - sortStrings ["World", "Hello"];
   > val it = ["Hello", "World"] : string list
   ```

   The quirk with this library is that Moscow ML's interactive REPL does not auto-load `Listsort`. Typing `load "Listsort";` is only necessary in the interactive REPL; when compiling programs, `load` is not used.
3. In Poly/ML, there is no library for sorting, so you have to define your own sorting function.

---

If neither of these sorting functions are sufficient, here is a number of other sorting functions written in Standard ML:

1. [True QuickSort in Standard ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101051/true-quicksort-in-standard-ml) compares a [naive QuickSort](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Standard_ML) (that isn't really a QuickSort) with an implementation of [Hoare's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) by John Coleman.
2. [Rosetta Code's MergeSort in Standard ML](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#Standard_ML):

   ```
   fun merge cmp ([], ys) = ys
     | merge cmp (xs, []) = xs
     | merge cmp (xs as x::xs', ys as y::ys') =
         case cmp (x, y) of
              GREATER => y :: merge cmp (xs, ys')
            | _       => x :: merge cmp (xs', ys)

   fun sort cmp [] = []
     | sort cmp [x] = [x]
     | sort cmp xs =
       let
         val ys = List.take (xs, length xs div 2)
         val zs = List.drop (xs, length xs div 2)
       in
         merge cmp (sort cmp ys, sort cmp zs)
       end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a standard quicksort

```
fun qsort(func) =
    let fun sort [] = []
          | sort (lhd :: ltl) =
                sort (List.filter (fn x => func (x, lhd)) ltl)
              @ [lhd]
              @ sort (List.filter (fn x => not (func(x, lhd)) ltl)
    in sort
    end
```

Just throw in some comparator (function that takes two elements with same type and return boolean) and it will return a sort function for you
If you got anymore question don't hesitate to ask. :)

Comment: by the way, this sorter will preserve order if and only if func(x,y) = false for x = y

Answer (score 0):

How about this for sorting a list? You could always use reverse to get the reverse.

```
- fun sort(L) =
   if L=[] then []
   else if tl(L)=[] then L
   else merge(sort(take(L)), sort(skip(L)));
 val sort = fn : int list -> int list
```

See [here](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~leo/CSE215/cse215FctProgramming.pdf).

Comment: What are merge, take and skip? Sorry to ask, but there's really zilch documentation out there.

Comment: So I assume there isn't a standard sort function in SML, right?

Comment: No you have to create your own

Answer (score 0):

here is my sml sorting algorithm

```
fun sort list = foldr (fn (x,lst)=> List.filter (fn a => a < x) lst @ [x] @ List.filter (fn a => a >= x) lst ) [] list;

sort [5,1,5,0,2,5,~2,5,~10,0];

output: [~10,~2,0,0,1,2,5,5,5,5]
```

I hope it helps