# can we call this function a quick sort

Tags: python, complexity-theory, quicksort

I found this function written in python on the internet and I'm confused if it's a quick sort or not because it's written in one line and it work very well and quickly and I think that it work with the complexity of O (n*log n) even in the worst case, so this is the code:

```
def qsort(L): 
  return (qsort([x for x in L[1:] if x < L[0]]) +\
          L[0:1] + \
          qsort([x for x in L[1:] if x >= L[0]])) if L else []
```

Comment: Looks like a Quicksort.

Comment: Break this one liner into multiple lines to make sense of it. One liners just for the sake of it often are a poor idea if it hinders readability...

Comment: Yes, it’s a quicksort. (It uses less-than-optimal space, but it still counts.)

Comment: Yes that looks like quicksort. But keep in mind that the worst case complexity of quicksort is O(n^2), not O(n*log n).

Comment: To build on previous comment: look at what happens when the input list is already in order.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i think so .

Comment: This is virtually identical to a version that is frequently taught in introductions to functional programming, often using Haskell or ML. Some regard it as not a "true" quicksort since it some ways it doesn't really follow Hoare's original algorithm very closely. That is possible semantics, Here are a couple of questions discussing the issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7717691/4996248 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/42101051/4996248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's quick sort as it's perfectly matching this algorithm definition: pick up arbitrary element from the list, move values lower than this element to the beginning of the list (before selected element) and perform quick sort recursively:

```
qsort([x for x in L[1:] if x < L[0]])
```

bigger or equal values to the end of the list (after selected element) and perform quick sort recursively

```
qsort([x for x in L[1:] if x >= L[0]])
```

if list is empty (recursion termination) then of course result is empty list.

Comment: I think so but when i test her speed i found it better then megeSort

Comment: As far as I remember while both merge and quick sort have avarage complexity nlogn quick sort performs better when it comes to typical random distributions