# Quick Sort Error using SML

Tags: sorting, sml

I learned SML last week so I tried to make Quicksort code to understand it well.
My code is:

```
fun quicksort(l: int list) =
    if length l < 2
    then l
    else let fun split(l:int list, v: int) =
        if null l
        then ([], [])
        else if v > hd l
        then ((hd l)::(#1 split(tl l, v)), #2 split(tl l, v))
        else (#1 split(tl l, v), (hd l)::(#2 split(tl l, v)))
    in
        (#1 split(quicksort(tl l), hd l)) @ ((hd l)::(#2 split(quicksort(tl l), hd l)))
    end
```

and this is the error message:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.75 [built: Sat Sep 29 12:51:13 2012]
- stdIn:21.18-21.35 Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {1:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int list * int -> 'X
  in expression:
    (fn {1=1,...} => 1) split
stdIn:21.8-21.56 Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {2:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int list * int -> 'X
  in expression:
    (fn {2=2,...} => 2) split
stdIn:22.8-22.56 Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {1:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int list * int -> 'X
  in expression:
    (fn {1=1,...} => 1) split
stdIn:22.37-22.54 Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {2:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int list * int -> 'X
  in expression:
    (fn {2=2,...} => 2) split
stdIn:24.4-24.35 Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {1:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int list * int -> int list * _ list
  in expression:
    (fn {1=1,...} => 1) split
stdIn:24.49-24.80 Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {2:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int list * int -> int list * _ list
  in expression:
    (fn {2=2,...} => 2) split
-
```

I set the head of the given list as pivot, and split the list into int list pairs and merge them again.

I think there are no type-matching problem but I don't no why it doesn't works.
Plz give some help for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code in [Moscow ML](http://mosml.org/) to highlight the problem code:

```
! Toplevel input:
!         then ((hd l)::(#1 split(tl l, v)), #2 split(tl l, v))
!                           ^^^^^
! Type clash: expression of type
!   int list * int -> int list * 'a list
! cannot have type
!   {1 : 'b, ...}
```

This type error suggests that an expression of type *int list × int -> int list × 'a list* is used where another part of the code expected it to be of type *{1 : 'b, ...}*. The first type is a function and the last type is a record with at least one entry in it.

The problem is that `#1 split(tl l, v)` is interpreted as `(#1 split)(tl l, v)` and not, as you intended, `#1 (split (tl l, v))`. That is, you want the first record entry of the *result* of the function, not of the function itself; that is nonsensical.. While `#1` is in fact a macro and not a function, it behaves syntactically like a function and should be composed as such.

Since you're doing QuickSort in SML, you may be intredasted in the question [True QuickSort in Standard ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101051/true-quicksort-in-standard-ml) that contains 1) RosettaCode's version that uses pattern matching rather than those scary partial functions like `hd` and `tl` that will crash your program unexpectedly at runtime, and 2) a version of QuickSort by John Coleman that is actually, algorithmically, a QuickSort. :-P

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really want to vote your answer up but I can't because of my reputation :(

Comment: @Rexion: You're welcome. Since you asked the question, you can mark the answer as "accepted".