# SML: Value restriction error when recursively calling quicksort

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm writing a quicksort function for an exercise.  I already know of the 5-line functional quicksort; but I wanted to improve the partition by having it scan through the list once and return a pair of lists splitting the original list in half.  So I wrote:

```ml
fun partition nil = (nil, nil)
  | partition (pivot :: rest) =
  let
    fun part (lst, pivot, (lesseq, greater)) =
      case lst of
           [] => (lesseq, greater)
         | (h::t) =>
             if h <= pivot then part (t, pivot, (h :: lesseq, greater))
             else part (t, pivot, (lesseq, h :: greater))
  in
    part (rest, pivot, ([pivot], []))
  end;
```

This partitions well enough.  It gives me a signature `val partition = fn : int list -> int list * int list`.  It runs as expected.

It's when I use the quicksort below that things start to break.

```ml
fun quicksort_2 nil = nil
  | quicksort_2 lst = 
let
  val (lesseq, greater) = partition lst
in
  quicksort_2 lesseq @ quicksort_2 greater
end;
```

I can run the above function if I eliminate the recursive calls to `quicksort_2`; but if I put them back in (to actually go and sort the thing), it will cease to run.  The signature will be incorrect as well, giving me `val quicksort_2 = fn : int list -> 'a list`. The warning I receive when I call the function on a list is:

```
Warning: type vars not generalized because of value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
```

What is the problem here? I'm not using any `ref` variables; the type annotation I've tried doesn't seem to help...

Comment: You may be interested in the Q&A [True QuickSort in Standard ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101051/true-quicksort-in-standard-ml) that references why this naive functional approach isn't really a QuickSort, and where John Coleman provides an actual QuickSort in the style of SML. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you're lacking the singleton list base case for your quicksort function. It ought to be

```ml
fun quicksort [ ] = [ ]
  | quicksort [x] = [x]
  | quicksort xs  = 
      let
        val (l, r) = partition xs
      in
        quicksort l @ quicksort r
      end
```

which should then have type `int list -> int list` given the type of your `partition`. We have to add this case as otherwise you'll never hit a base case and instead recurse indefinitely.

---

For some more detail on why you saw the issues you were having though:

> The signature will be incorrect as well, giving me `val quicksort_2 = fn : int list -> 'a list`

This is because the codomain of your function was never restricted to be less general than `'a list`. Taking a look at the possible branches in your original implementation we can see that in the `nil` branch you return `nil` (of most general type `'a list`) and in the recursive case you get two `'a list`s (per our assumptions thus far) and append them, resulting in an `'a list`---this is fine so your type is not further restricted.

> [Value Restriction Warning]
> What is the problem here? I'm not using any `ref` variables

The value restriction isn't really related to `ref`s (though can often arise when using them). Instead it is the prohibition that anything polymorphic at the top level must be a value by its syntax (and thus precludes the possibility that a computation is behind a type abstractor at the top level). Here it is because given `xs : int list` we (ignoring the value restriction) have `quicksort_2 xs : 'a list`---which would otherwise be polymorphic, but is not a syntactic value. Correspondingly it is value restricted.