# Sort list of tuples lexicographically

Tags: sml, ml

I was trying to create a function in Standard ML which gets a list of `string * int` and returns a lexicography sorted list.

For example foo `[("y",5),("x",10)]` will return `[("x,10),("y",5)]` (only the first element of each tuple is important).

I wrote the following lines:

```
fun foo ([]:(string * int)) = []
  | foo [x] = [x]
  | foo ((x,y)::xs) = 
    let
      val (s,t) = hd(xs) (* gets next element string *)
      fun sort ... = ...
    in

    end
```

I don't know how to implement the `sort` function but I would like it to have the following code I wrote:

```
    case String.compare(x,s) of
      LESS => ...
    | EQUAL => ...
    | GREATER => ...
```

Also I need to use `val (s,t) = hd(xs)` in the `sort` function so it will be recursive but Im not sure. further more, I'm not allowed any additional libraries - only work with hidden let/local.

Comment: You don't have to use `hd(xs)`. You can use pattern matching instead.

Answer (score 0):

*(If you were allowed to use library functions,)* [`ListMergeSort.sort`](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/listsort.html) in SML/NJ looks like:

> ```
> val sort : ('a * 'a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
> ```
>
> *`sort f l`* returns a list of the elements in *`l`*, sorted in non-decreasing order as specified by the ``greater than'' predicate *`f`*. Specifically, if *`f(x,y)`* evaluates to true, then *`x`* will appear after *`y`* in the resulting list.

Using this library function to write your `foo`:

```
fun foo pairs = ListMergeSort.sort (fn ((s : string,_), (t,_)) => s > t)
```

This might look a little different if you use another compiler than SML/NJ.

---

To address your sub-problems,

> I don't know how to implement the `sort` function

*(Since you're not allowed any library functions,)* you could build a sorting function that takes `String.compare` as argument. Depending on the sorting algorithm, a rough sketch of the sorting function could look like:

```
fun sort cmp [] = []
  | sort cmp [x] = [x]
  | sort cmp xs = ... partially sort xs using `cmp`, combine results ...
```

and its signature would be `('a * 'a -> order) -> 'a list -> 'a list`.

You're not asking how to make a sorting function (but merely saying that you don't know how to), and if you were, I would be inclined to say that this question is too broad when you don't specify what kind of algorithm you wish to implement, or where you got stuck in the process. See for example [Rosetta Code's MergeSort](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#Standard_ML), or the Q&A [Standard sorting functions in SML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411862/standard-sorting-functions-in-sml)

> I would like it to have the following code I wrote:
>
> ```
> case String.compare (x,s) of ...
> ```
>
> *[...]* I'm not allowed any additional libraries *[...]*

But `String.compare` is a library function, too! You could write your own `String.compare`. Either *(a)* *explode* the strings into char lists and use list recursion to determine their lexicographical order, or *(b)* *count* the length of the strings and use `String.sub (s, i)` to get the *`i`th* char of *`s`* for each string until the lexicographical order is determined. While *(b)* is more efficient (since it uses a small, constant amount of memory), *(a)* is a fine exercise in list recursion.

For *(a)* you could start with:

```
fun stringCompare (s, t) =
    let fun cmp (x::xs, y::ys) = if x < y then ... else ...
          | cmp (_::_, [])     = ...
          | cmp ([], _::_)     = ...
          | cmp ([], [])       = EQUAL
    in cmp (explode s, explode t) end
```

You can then compose them in the same way:

```
fun foo pairs = sort (fn ((s,_), (t,_)) => stringCompare (s, t)) pairs
```