# Lexicographically sorting a list of neasted lists

Tags: sml

Consider the following nested list:

```
[["AXY"],["ABC","XYZ"],["EFG","ACF"]]
```

I would like to sort the list lexicographically by the first element of each inner list. The output should be:

```
[["ABC","XYZ"],["AXY"],["EFG","ACF"]]
```

If the task have been to sort only one list, I would use one of the methods in the following thread ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411862/standard-sorting-functions-in-sml/14412749)). But how can I sort a nested list?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a generic sort function taking a cmp function (like the one shown [at the bottom of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50340381/1016216)), you just need to write one taking two string lists:

```
fun cmpnest ((x::xs):string list, (y::ys):string list) = if x > y then GREATER else LESS
|   cmpnest ((x::xs):string list, nil) = GREATER
|   cmpnest (nil, _) = LESS
```

After you have that, you can use it in your generic sort function:

```
- sort cmpnest [["AXY"], ["ABC", "XYZ"], ["EFG", "ACF"]];
> val it = [["ABC", "XYZ"], ["AXY"], ["EFG", "ACF"]] : string list list
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to L3viathan's answer, you can also use `String.compare`:

```
fun cmpnest (x::_, y::_) = String.compare (x, y)
  | cmpnest (_::_, []) = GREATER
  | cmpnest ([], _) = LESS
```