# Why does this SML mergeSort function not return a sorted list?

Tags: mergesort, sml

It ends up returning nothing. Also, when run, it says it is:

```
- val merge_sort = fn : ('a * 'a -> bool) -> 'b list -> 'a list
```

When I know it should be this:

```
- val merge_sort = fn : ('a * 'a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

The function:

```
fun merge_sort f = 
    let
        fun merge(nil, ylist) = ylist
        |   merge(xlist, nil) = xlist
        |   merge(x::xend, y::yend) =
        if f (x,y) then
            x::merge(xend, y::yend)
        else
            y::merge(x::xend, yend)

        fun split nil = (nil, nil) 
        |   split [x] = ([x], nil)
        |   split (x::y::xy) = 
            let 
                val (low, up) = split xy
            in 
                (x::low, y::up)
            end

    in
        let
            fun real nil = nil
            | real L = 
                let
                    val (list1,list2) = split L
                in
                    merge (real list1,real list2)
            end
        in
             fn last => real last
        end
    end;

 merge_sort (op >) [0, 5, 1, ~4, 9, 11]
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote because there is no attempt at debugging, but I encourage you to read https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ - in particular, "Debugging code is one of the most important things that a developer can do. When a program’s result is unexpected, or when a program crashes at runtime, debugging is a way for a developer to quickly isolate and identify the problem. In the vast majority of cases, once the problem is identified, the solution is clear. But when a developer does not debug their code, the problem becomes much harder to fix."

Comment: Comparing your solution to the solutions provided in the Q&A [Standard sorting functions in SML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411862/standard-sorting-functions-in-sml) should be another way to detect the bug besides debugging as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The funny type is actually somewhat related to the bug that makes your function never terminate.

Removing the custom comparison and separating the helpers (and collapsing `merge_sort` and `real`):

```
fun split nil = (nil, nil) 
  | split [x] = ([x], nil)
  | split (x::y::xy) = 
    let 
        val (low, up) = split xy
    in 
        (x::low, y::up)
    end;

fun merge (nil, ylist) = ylist
  | merge (xlist, nil) = xlist
  | merge (x::xend, y::yend) =
    if x < y then
        x::merge (xend, y::yend)
    else
        y::merge (x::xend, yend);


fun merge_sort nil = nil
  | merge_sort L =
    let
        val (list1,list2) = split L
    in
        merge (merge_sort list1, merge_sort list2)
    end;
```

we get these types:

```
val split = fn : 'a list -> 'a list * 'a list
val merge = fn : int list * int list -> int list
val merge_sort = fn : 'a list -> int list
```

and `merge_sort` takes a list of anything and produces an `int list`.
That's weird.
Let's look at how that was arrived at.

```
fun merge_sort nil = nil
```

`nil` can be a list of anything, so that gives `'a list -> 'a list`.

```
| merge_sort L =
  let
      val (list1,list2) = split L
  in
      merge (merge_sort list1, merge_sort list2)
  end;
```

Now, the result must be `int list`, because that's what `merge` produces, and that also agrees with the parameters of `merge`.
But there is still no way to infer a more specific type from `merge_sort`'s parameter - it's only passed back to `merge_sort`, and `'a list` is what we've already got, so  we end up with `'a list -> int list`.

Look at what happens when you sort a singleton list:

```
    merge-sort [1]
--> let val (list1, list2) = split [1] in merge (merge_sort list1, merge_sort list2)
--> merge (merge_sort [1], merge_sort [])
```

and we have a recursion that doesn't terminate.

You need a separate base case for a singleton list:

```
| merge_sort [x] = [x]
```

and when you add that, the types are what they should be.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! you were right, it was the issue of "real"s ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a debugging problem, here is how I might go about finding the problem:

First, I run the program and realize it throws an `Out_of_memory` exception. So I know that there's some infinite recursion going on. Somewhere a recursive call is supposed to hit a base case, but it isn't, and instead it calls itself until it eventually runs out of memory.

The function consists of multiple helper functions. See if they all work as intended.

Because `merge` is embedded as an inner function of `merge_sort`, it is hard to test in isolation because you can't refer directly to it, and if you move it out, it fails to compile because it expects the comparison function `f` from its parent scope. So I'm going to change `merge` slightly for testability purposes.

The `split` function doesn't need a similar modification, and the `real` function seems kind of unnecessary since it is just the merge-sort function; the `let` within a `let` also seems unnecessary, but since I'm moving all the helper functions out, those will be removed as a consequence anyway. So I'm going to remove `real` and just call it `mergeSort`.

The result (with some extra renaming of `nil` into `[]` and so on, which is just my preference):

```
fun merge p ([], ys) = ys
  | merge p (xs, []) = xs
  | merge p (x::xs, y::ys) =
      if p (x,y) then
        x::merge p (xs, y::ys)
      else
        y::merge p (x::xs, ys)

fun split [] = ([], [])
  | split [x] = ([x], [])
  | split (x::y::xys) =
    let
      val (lo, hi) = split xys
    in
      (x::lo, y::hi)
    end

fun mergeSort p [] = []
  | mergeSort p zs =
    let
      val (xs, ys) = split zs
    in
      merge p (mergeSort p xs, mergeSort p ys)
    end
```

Testing this, it still throws an `Out_of_memory` error, so I didn't actually fix anything.

Let's try and run it by hand on a small input;

- Every line that begins with `=` below signifies a term rewrite where I've replaced some part of the former expression with its definition. For example, `mergeSort (op >) [1,2,3]`, which is the starting point, is replaced with the definition of `mergeSort` on the input that pattern matches `[1,2,3]`.
- Every line that begins with <kbd>`-</kbd> is my attempt to expand on a sub-part of an expression without including that in the total rewrite of the above expression -- otherwise that might get a bit messy.

```
  mergeSort (op >) [1,2,3]
= let val (xs, ys) = split [1,2,3] in merge (op >) (mergeSort (op >) xs, mergeSort (op >) ys) end
   `-   split [1,2,3]
      = let val (lo, hi) = split [3] in (1::lo, 2::hi) end
      = let val (lo, hi) = ([3], []) in (1::lo, 2::hi) end
      = (1::[3], 2::[])
      = ([1,3], [2])
= let val (xs, ys) = ([1,3], [2]) in merge (op >) (mergeSort p xs, mergeSort p ys) end
= merge (op >) (mergeSort (op >) [1,3], mergeSort (op >) [2])
   `-   mergeSort (op >) [1,3]
      = let val (xs, ys) = split [1,3] in merge (op >) (mergeSort (op >) xs, mergeSort (op >) ys) end
         `-   split [1,3]
            = let val (lo, hi) = split [] in (1::lo, 3::hi) end
            = let val (lo, hi) = ([], []) in (1::lo, 3::hi) end
            = (1::[], 3::hi)
            = ([1], [3])
      = let val (xs, ys) = ([1], [3]) in merge (op >) (mergeSort (op >) xs, mergeSort (op >) ys) end
      = merge (op >) (mergeSort (op >) [1], mergeSort (op >) [3])
         `-   mergeSort (op >) [1]
            = let val (xs, ys) = split [1] in merge (op >) (mergeSort (op >) xs, mergeSort (op >) ys) end
            = let val (xs, ys) = ([1], []) in merge (op >) (mergeSort (op >) xs, mergeSort (op >) ys) end
            = merge (op >) (mergeSort (op >) [1], mergeSort (op >) [])
               `- OOPS!
```

I don't know if you noticed, but in my attempt to calculate `mergeSort (op >) [1]`, I was very quickly asked to calculate `mergeSort (op >) [1]` as part of its result. But doing that I'll quickly end up doing that again, and again, and again. So it appears, from running the function by hand, that the infinite recursion is located in what I call `mergeSort` and what your code calls `real`.

This is a bug in the algorithm that can be fixed by stating something about the sortedness of a singleton list.

---

As a side note, here's how I might rewrite this function entirely:

```
fun merge cmp ([], ys) = ys
  | merge cmp (xs, []) = xs
  | merge cmp (xs as x::xs', ys as y::ys') =
      case cmp (x, y) of
           GREATER => y :: merge cmp (xs, ys')
         | _       => x :: merge cmp (xs', ys)

fun sort cmp [] = []
  | sort cmp [x] = [x]
  | sort cmp xs =
    let
      val ys = List.take (xs, length xs div 2)
      val zs = List.drop (xs, length xs div 2)
    in
      merge cmp (sort cmp ys, sort cmp zs)
    end

fun down LESS = GREATER
  | down GREATER = LESS
  | down EQUAL = EQUAL
```

(I've preserved the bug.)

Sorting integers is now:

```
sort (fn (x,y) => down (Int.compare (x,y))) [1,2,3]
```